# Fastest way to loop through video and save frames

Tags: python, loops, opencv, computer-vision, pickle

I need to extract frames and landmarks from a video in one process, and then perform operations of the frames and landmarks in another process. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Right now, I am storing frames as arrays in a list, and then pickling that list. Code below:

```
frames, landmarks = [], []
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
while cap.isOpened():
    success, frame = cap.read()
    lm = get_landmarks(frame)
    frames.append(frame)
    landmarks.append(lm)

frame_pickle = open(f"frames.pkl", "wb")
landmarks_pickle = open(f"landmarks.pkl", "wb")
pickle.dump(data_out, frame_pickle)
pickle.dump(frame_number_out, landmarks_pickle)
```

This works, but it is very slow. Is there anyway I can speed this up/make this more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `get_landmarks` function performs facial recognition, there is not really any way to speed this up. You can attempt to multithread it, by creating batches of threads, to process in parallel. Other than that, it looks like your main bottleneck would be the `get_landmarks` function.

Answer (score 0):

As rightly pointed out by Rainer, it is the get_landmarks function which is the bottle neck. If the `get_landmarks` function is using some deep learning model to extract the landmarks, then you can pass the images as a batch and get a speed up there.

Also currently your process 2 (the process which reads the pickle files and process them further) runs after you have extracted the landmarks for the entire video, if the landmarks of the entire video are not required to start processing the pickle files, you can write to the pickle file after every x frames.